# Parse.com: Retrieving object by objectId does not work. Why? It is very simple query

Tags: parse-platform

I got an error with message "101 Object not found."

The below code is just copy from the official guide. And I changed the class name and the objectId.

I know this is very simple query but I don't know why? Help me how to debug in this case...

This code is in cloud code. I set up "applicationId" and "masterKey" in global.json.

Thanks..

```
require('cloud/app.js');

Parse.Cloud.define("sample", function(request, response) {

  var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Item");
  var query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
  query.get("XXXXXX", {
    success: function(gameScore) {

    },
    error: function(object, error) {
      console.error("error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the name of the object you are getting? GameScore or Item?

Comment: @Fogmeister thanks for quick response. I have Item class in Parse.com.

Comment: And you're positive the object ID exists in the Item table? If you add it as a filter in the Core dashboard you should be able to see it.

Comment: Yes I did double check it.

Comment: Where did you place your masterKey? Client side?

Comment: Hi. No, masterKey is in global.json. This code is cloud code.

Comment: The code looks fine. Could you check both the permission of table and object?

Comment: permission? how can I see..? I will check it now

Comment: I found that public check boxes were empty.

Comment: You could check it via app's data browser. The security button will show class level permission and the ACL column shows the object's permission.

Comment: It worked finally!!!! I changed the object's permission.

Comment: Is it possible that giving public read permission when creating the object? I guess it is possible .. ok I will check it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to use the promise method and I'd possibly rewrite it like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sample", function(request, response) {
    var query = new Parse.Query("Item");

    // put this in as a debug message.
    console.log("Just checking I'm here!");

    query.get("XXXXXX").then (function(item) {
        response.success(item);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

But it should work as it is. Odd. Are you sure the error message is coming from your code?

Try adding a log before it.

**EDIT**

It seems that permissions were not set properly on your item object.

With iOS you can specify a default ACL for objects at create time. You can also create a custom ACL object and pass it to the object when saving it.

Comment: Sorry it does not work... I got this message "error: undefined"

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's completely my fault. The permission was the reason.

Comment: Thanks your additional comment. I could put public permission to an object at create time. I am using Parse.com on Android.